# Regular Expressions: Pound Sign at beginning of word

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

I am trying to find words starting with a pound sign. Javascript.

```
"test #word no#luck".replace( /\b#([\w]+)\b/g, "<#$1>" );
```

yet the word boundary doesn't seem to apply to the #-sign. it outputs:

```
test #word no<#luck>
```

also i am a bit confused that i need to add the #-sign again in the replacement pattern "<#$1>", as the algorithm seems to strip it in the process.

Comment: The problem is that "#" is itself **not** a word character; therefore it doesn't make sense for there to be a non-word to word transition before it.

Comment: because of # is not a word character ( which are [a-zA-Z0-9_] ) every word after # sign will be matched.

Comment: Instead of `\b` you want `(?=[^\w#])`.

Comment: The needle `\W(#\w+)` works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```js
result = subject.replace(/(^|\s)(#\w+)\b/g, "$1<$2>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = subject.replace(/(?:^|\s)(#\w+)(?:\s|$)/g, "<$1>");
```

`\b` will only work with `\w`